# How to copy a region or a whole buffer to another buffer in Emacs without affecting the kill ring?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to copy the region to another (temporary) buffer in Emacs, but if there's no (acive) region, I'd like to copy the whole current buffer.  What I did is as follows:

```elisp
(defun do-something-with-region-or-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((begin (point-min)) (end (point-max)))
      (when (region-active-p)
        (setq begin (region-beginning))
        (setq end (region-end)))
      (copy-region-as-kill begin end)
      (with-temp-buffer
        (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
        (rename-buffer "*My Temp Buffer*")
        (delete-other-windows)
        (yank)
        (do-something-with-current-buffer)))))
```

However, I have a strong feeling that this is suboptimal, since I'm messing around with the kill ring.  How to do it without affecting it?  (Bonus question: is my way of doing things with the region *or* the whole buffer *if* there's no active region a good one?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how I would do it:

```
(defun aak/dswrob ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((regionp (region-active-p))
         (beg (and regionp (region-beginning)))
         (end (and regionp (region-end)))
         (buf (current-buffer)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer) nil t)
      (rename-buffer "*My Temp Buffer*" t)
      (insert-buffer-substring buf beg end)
      (read-key-sequence "Keys?"))))
```

It's up to you to decide if you want `insert-buffer-substring` or
`insert-buffer-substring-no-properties`, but there is no need to use
kill rings.

Also it's rather strange to do something interactively within
`with-temp-buffer`: are you going to run a kind of modal loop there,
or is it just displaying some progress?

As of doing things with the region *or* the whole buffer (NB: modulo
*narrowing*), it's not quite unusual (see `replace-string` and
friends).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  If no other, better answer appears, I'll accept this one tomorrow or so.

As for `with-temp-buffer`: it is kind of a visual toy, doing something funny with the contents of the current buffer, and I want it to disappear when it's finished.